# Uncaught Error in snapshot listener:, [FirebaseError: inequality filter property and first sort order must be the same: __name__ and date]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I try to get some documents with the onSnpashot method and in the same times apply where (for filter the collection) and orderBy (for sort my results). I make a composite index (with documentId() field, and date) but it don't work... I hope you can help me.
[This is my structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0c3f.png)

```
var ColRef = collection(DB_Firestore, "ListConv");
var q = query(ColRef, where(documentId(), "in", ["Oe4VQzzcLh1aKWedt7yU"]), orderBy("date", "desc"));
return onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
  if(!snapshot.empty) {
    var changes = snapshot.docChanges();
    changes.map(change => {
      if(change.type == "added") {
        var conv = change.doc.data();
        conv["uid"] = change.doc.id;
        setConv(Conv => [...Conv, conv]);
      }
    });
    setLoadData(false);
  } else {
    setLoadData(false);
  }
})
```

Also I try to put the inside my hook's Array "Conv"; And get my handler in order to unsubscribe it.
Thank's for all. Good Night !

Comment: Read the error message carefully - the first field to sort on in your query must be the same as the field you used in your filter.  Your filter is on document ID (\_name\_), but your ordering is on date.  This is not valid with Firestore.  Indexes won't help until you fix the query.

Comment: Thanks Doug for your response. I know I must have the exact same field. However, with a request of the getDoc type, the creation of an index solved my problem, always relating to two different fields. So I don't understand why the same method wouldn't work for onSnapShot?

Comment: Queries work the same no matter if they are through snapshot listeners or individual queries.  If you observe that they behave differently, please post a new question explaining in more detail what does not work the way you expect, compared to the code that does work.

Comment: Okay so I found the solution, when I put (where("uid", "in", [...]), orderBy("date")) instead of (where(documentId(), "in", [...]), orderBy("date")). Firebase propose to me to create an index composite, and it works. Can you explain me what's the difference. I think this is juste le the level of two values.

Comment: Please post a new question with these details.